# Counting words in a string in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have to make a program that uses a text file containing multiple lines and counts how many words are in the file.

Normally this would be easy, since the number of words in a line = the number of spaces + 1. So I could just loop through a line and increment a variable whenever it encounters the ascii code for space. But the catch here is that words have a varied number of spaces between them, so this method is not possible. I suppose I could just ignore spaces that are back-to-back with another space, but I'm not entirely sure how I could implement this.

I'm not asking anyone to write any code for me or anything, I just need some help on how else I can approach/solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you want to count the number of transitions from spaces to non-spaces (or vice versa).

Typically you end up with an `in_word` to signal whether you're current in a word (i.e., the last character was not a space). If in_word is true and the current character is a space, you increment the count (and set in_word to false).

Comment: Does NASM have an equivalent of a bool condition? Or should 'in_word' just be a normal variable that I just set to either 0 or 1?

Comment: @Slavic_Donut: I'd at least try to keep `in_word` in a register.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an approach similar to what you have suggested; count spaces but ignore duplicated spaces between words.

Also make sure that you ignore the spaces before and after each line.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the number of words in a text is a textbook example for the application of state machines; see e.g. this article: http://media.pragprog.com/articles/nov_02_state.pdf

There is a diagram of the state machine for word counting on the second page; translating this into assembly code should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

consider using strtok from the kernel. just add it at the start:

```
extern strtok
```

and then learn how to use it, definitely simpler than inventing your own :D